# What is a proper way to simplify an accepted but long answer for my own question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Consider I have a question which got a big comprehensive answer, which fully clarified the question to me. But it's not just a comprehensive explanation: none of other shorter answers I saw actually helped me understand the problem, though they were still correct answers technically. I just didn't see the clue in them.

What my current question is about, is: what is proper way to add a simplified answer to my own question (roughly-speaking - one-line sentence), but leaving that initial answer still accepted? I feel a need for this, because other short answers didn't help, and I wouldn't have come to a short answer without that comprehensive one.

Comment: Depending on the situation, it might be appropriate to edit (or suggest an edit to) the comprehensive answer to add a TL;DR section to it.

Comment: I can't see a reason to add another answer when there is already a full and correct answer. That would be just noise. (Same as repeating existing answers.)

Answer (score 4):

"One line sentence" would probably indicate a comment might suffice—something along the lines of "I found that in my case the suggestion to remodulate the transverse tachyon flux capacitor solved the problem with the exploding tribbles". It’s not a 'thank you'; it’s also a pointer at what specifically caused it.

Comment: Please don't encourage using comments to write answers instead of the Answer section.

Comment: Its not - in this case. There's already an answer that covers the solution ands a little more. It just clarifies that *part* of the answer helped.

Comment: That's what upvotes and acceptance and bounties are for.

Comment: Well it says the answer as a whole helped - not if it was a specific part of it.

Comment: Asking for that part to be emphasised would be a useful comment - suggesting improvements to the answer in order to increase clarity. But, just saying "I liked this bit the most" is at least in part achievable with bounties, and at best irrelevant meta commentary.

Answer (score 4):

> simplified answer to my own question (roughly-speaking - one-line sentence)

While this one line answer would help clarify the solution to your problem, you may find other don't see your clue. Essentially, other people may need bits of the other answers to solve their problem.

I would either leave comments on the answer you feel could use clarification or propose an edit to an answer that highlights or clarifies the "clue" you needed.